# Using Doctrine commands in Netbeans

Tags: doctrine

[In this video at youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3xjfbtQtDRE), You can see at 0:50 that the person has integrated Doctrine Commands in the Netbeans. I want to know how we can integrate Doctrine commands to use with Netbeans instead of cmd in windows. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to read this article :
[Creating doctrine cli and adding it to zend tool](http://roysimkes.net/blog/2009/12/creating-doctrine-cli-and-adding-it-to-zend_tool/)

Then, if you don't really know how to integrate Zend tool with Netbeans try to read this good tutorial : [how to configure zend tool and netbeans](http://www.kilinjal.com/blog/how-configure-zend-tool-netbeans)

I hope that you'll find a solution